# Jade, Bootstrap 3 - Can't click on positioned checkbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, pug

I'm using Bootstrap 3 checkbox and it looks like this by default:

[image: image 1]

When I move the checkbox position to the right, it moves but can't be clicked.

Here is the **Jade** structure (please ignore the second to last line indentation, it doesn't look like that and perfectly works in my page):

```
.row.good-entry.no-pad
         .col-xs-1.col-sm-1
          .checkbox
           input#check1(type='checkbox', value="")
           label(for='check1')
         .col-xs-11.col-sm-11
          .row
           .col-xs-6.col-sm-8.good-info
            ul
             li
              .good-title Nama Item
              p Kiraniar Plain Casual Cardigan
             li
              .good-title SKU
              p RP-3994-ARL-4595
             li
              .good-title Harga Satuan
              p 193000
```

and this is my **CSS** to change the checkbox position:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
   margin-left: 10px !important;
}
```

I hope you guys can help me since I've been stuck pretty long in these stuffs. Any help appreciated. :)

**edit**:
I tried to directly edit the position in Bootstrap CSS (lol) by only 5px, and it shown that I still can click the checkbox but only if I click on the edge of it (it seems like the "clickable element" doesn't move alongside the checkbox itself). But I still can't figure out what is it and why does it happen.

I knew it would result the same but this **CSS** also doesn't work:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
   -ms-transform: translateX(10px);
   -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
   transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

Also moving the checkbox's parent (or its parent's parent) gave the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title Jade
  link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')
  body
    .container
      .row
        .col-sm-1
          .checkbox
            input#check1(type='checkbox', value='')
            label(for='check1')
        .col-sm-11
          .row
            .col-xs-6.col-sm-8.good-info
              ul
                li
                  .good-title Nama Item
                  p Kiraniar Plain Casual Cardigan
                li
                  .good-title SKU
                  p RP-3994-ARL-4595
                li
                  .good-title Harga Satuan
                  p 193000
```

Comment: Thank you, but are you trying to say I forgot to include the Bootstrap CSS or the header?

Comment: There should be css problem